# How to get clang-format Visual Studio 2015 Extension to not put braces on same line as the if statement

Tags: visual-studio-2015, clang-format

From my point of View, for any language for which braces are optional, putting braces on the same line as the if statement is not desirable. Consider the following.

```
if (VeryLongConditionThatIsWiderThanScreen) {
// Thousands of lines of badly indented code.
// You cannot rely on indentation to tell you were the block ends.
}
```

If the brace is at the end of the if statement, I have to hunt for and press the end key just to determine where that code block ends. I hate doing that. I am a hunt and peck typist with poor vision and it takes considerable effort for me to find that end key just so I can find out where that code block ends.

I am trying to use clang-format, using the ClangFormat Visual Studio 2015 Extension, but I insist that it not put the braces on the same line as the if. All of the built in styles do. I read the documentation at http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html and wrote the following .clang-format file.

```
---
Language: Cpp
BasedOnStyle: WebKit
AlignAfterOpenBracket: AlwaysBreak
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: true
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: true
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
BraceWrapping:
    AfterControlStatement: true
    AfterEnum: true
    AfterStruct: true
    AfterUnion: true
    BeforeCatch: true
    BeforeElse: true
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BreakBeforeInheritanceComma: true
ColumnLimit: 100
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: true
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
IndentWidth: 2
SortIncludes: false
TabWidth: 2
...
```

If I interpreted the documentation correctly, then setting AfterControlStatement to true should cause clang-format to put the brace on the line after the if, which is what I want. This is not happening. I have put the .clang-format file in the same directory as my project file. I also tried naming it _clang-format. Nothing works. Every time I use the CLang Format Document menu item it puts all braces associated with the if statement on the same line as the if.

Comment: I think the following bug may have something to do with my issue: https://bugs.llvm.org//show_bug.cgi?id=25069.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that my problems were caused by the fact that I had AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine and AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine set to true.

This issue was reported as [bug 25069 (clang-format `BreakBeforeBraces` behavior changes with `Allow...OnASingleLine` parameters)](https://bugs.llvm.org//show_bug.cgi?id=25069).

I ended up using the following .clang-format file to achieve my goals.

```
---
Language: Cpp
BasedOnStyle: WebKit
AccessModifierOffset: -2
AlignAfterOpenBracket: AlwaysBreak
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: Empty
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: true
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: true
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BraceWrapping:
  AfterClass: true
  AfterControlStatement: true
  AfterEnum: true
  AfterFunction: true
  AfterNamespace: false
  AfterObjCDeclaration: true
  AfterStruct: true
  AfterUnion: true
  BeforeCatch: true
  BeforeElse: true
  IndentBraces: false
ColumnLimit: 100
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 2
ContinuationIndentWidth: 2
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
IndentWidth: 2
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false
PointerAlignment: Right
SortIncludes: false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: false
TabWidth: 2
UseTab: ForContinuationAndIndentation
...
```